# Browse button is not working in WebView android

Tags: android, android-studio, web-applications, webview, web

I am developing an application for my website. I am using WebView to open website in my application. Everything else is working fine. But whenever i try to click the Browse button in the website(running through webview in my application) then it is not working. Logcat displays this message. **Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread**  Please help me. how can i make application for my website in short time...

```
public class Temporary extends Activity {

private WebView wv;

private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                : intent.getData();
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;

    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    wv = new WebView(this);
    wv.loadUrl("My URl"); //I do not want to show real url
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        //The undocumented magic method override
        //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            Temporary.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

        }
    });

    setContentView(wv);
}
```

}

Is there any manifest permissions require except these:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Please help:)

This Browse button is not working at all as shown in image

[Browse Button image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB4gW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution of my problem and now Browse button is working fine on lollipop and marshmellow. you can refer this link https://www.opengeeks.me/2015/08/filechooser-and-android-webview/ 
if you are facing same problem. But It is for image browsing only.